# Video Stream Hosting

Tags: security, video-streaming, content-security-policy

Good day! I'm a newbie on video streaming. Can you help me find good ways on how to make a video streaming secure?

I'm having some issues on my video hosting project security.

I am creating a web page which calls a video stream hosted on a different server where
my web page is deployed.

Server 1(web page video embed) calls video to stream on Server 2(video host).

The problem is that they are hosted on an absolute different network. Should Server 2 where the video is hosted should be private and only allow Server 1 to fetch the video stream creating a server to server transfer of data, or should it be public for the clients to be able access it.

Can you help me decide what to do to secure my videos?

I badly need some idea on this... thanks guys!

Comment: I believe that routing the entire video data through server1 incurs a huge and unnecessary overhead. I would share relevant security data/tokens between the servers, but I'm no expert. Added tags to make the question more attractive to those I believe can deliver answers.

Comment: yeah.. i managed to include tokens to the urls embedded used for validity of the video. thanks sir! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you streaming and what streaming protocol are you using?

Server to server wont help in securing the video.it is better to stream the video direcly from your Server 2(video host) directly to the client,so that it wont be overhead for server 1(web page video embed).You need to use secure way to protect you video on server 2.if the server2 is not secure,even if you stream through server1 it wont help.

Here are details of security level on different video streamings.

1. If you are using progressive download.This can be done using normal http protocol.In this approach you would be able to see the video url in the browser.Once you got the url you can download it as a normal file download.Security is very low here.Even if you sign the video url,the user can download the video easily.
2. Streaming,you can stream the video using different protocol like rtmp etc.If you are streaming videos using some rtmp.In this approch, you wont be able to download the video directly,but you can use some good software to capture the video stream and save to the pc.
3. Streaming securly.There are some protocols like rtmpe.I tried only rtmpe,In this protocol,the streaming content will be encrypted on the server and decrypted on the client.so the software wont be able to capture the video stream.

   Along with approach 3,if you sign the video url,it will add more security.Hope this helps.